# R: Perl Regex for unicode character string

Tags: regex, r, pcre, gsub

I am trying to get rid of some unicode character strings spread out in my data.

```
Sample data <- "['oguma', 'makeup', u'\u0e27\u0e34\u0e15\u0e32\u0e21\u0e34\u0e19\u0e2b\u0e19\u0e49\u0e32\u0e40\u0e14\u0e47\u0e01', 'jeban',]"
```

I want to capture everything starting with a u'\ and include the comma at the end.

I was thinking of starting with:

```
gsub("u/\\/\'....
```

+ everything including the next comma, but I'm not sure how to say that second part.

For a result of:

```
Sample data <- "['oguma', 'makeup', 'jeban',]"
```

suggestions?

Comment: Do you expect the result to be `"['oguma', 'makeup', u'', 'jeban',]"`? Have a look at [this demo](http://ideone.com/cpoodW). The thing is, these are not literal codes, these are characters outside of ASCII range.

Comment: I don't know which engine R uses, but it's not Perl's (as nothing but `perl` uses that). Maybe it's PCRE? Adjusted tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a regex solution that will remove the substrings starting with `u'`, followed with non-ASCII characters (1 or more) and end with a comma (optional, 1 or 0) and whitespaces (also optional, 0 or more):

```
data <- "['oguma', 'makeup', u'\u0e27\u0e34\u0e15\u0e32\u0e21\u0e34\u0e19\u0e2b\u0e19\u0e49\u0e32\u0e40\u0e14\u0e47\u0e01', 'jeban',]"
gsub("u'[^[:ascii:]]+',?\\s*", "", data, perl=T)
## => [1] "['oguma', 'makeup', 'jeban',]"
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/cpoodW)

Note that the `\u0e27`-like substrings in your example are just non-ASCII characters that - if you print the string - will be displayed correctly as those letters/symbols (here, `u'วิตามินหน้าเด็ก'`, Thai for "vitamins for kids" - Google Translate).